# Words with Gomorrah as etymon

Tags: etymology

The name of the city of *Sodom* is the etymon of sodomy.

> **Question:** *Are there words in English for which Gomorrah is an etymon?*

According to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gomorrah&searchmode=none) the unit [*omer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omer_(unit)) is related to *Gomorrah*. Beyond this I haven't found other words that are, at least, related. It would be interesting to know.

Comment: How about 'Gonorrhea'?

Comment: @Mitch That comes from Lat. *gonos* (seed) and *rhoe* (flow) see [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gonorrhea&searchmode=none). There it also says that Gomoria (as a reference to Gomorrah) was used to refer to gonorrhea. But gonorrhea itself doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: There is the Latin term gomorrhaeus (Italian  "gomorreo") that derive from Gomorrah, meaning 'sodomite'. But I can't find english equivalent for this term.

Comment: @Josh61 Interesting! Languages tend to be rich and creative in sexual innuendos and terms related to sexuality in general. I find it puzzling that Gomorrah is not so much the source for that creativity as Sodom is. Maybe is it because the two names come usually together and Sodom is often first. Maybe because it was in Sodom where the incident with Lot and his guests happens in the story. Just wild-guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I can find in the OED is *Gomorr(h)ean*: of or pertaining to Gomorrah; an inhabitant of Gomorrah; or one who follows the inhabitants' practices.

The Online Etymology Dictionary isn't saying *omer* has *Gomorrah* as an etymon (i.e. that *omer* comes from *Gomorrah*), but the other way around: *Gomorrah* is from *omer*.

The OED says *omer* replaced the earlier *gomer*. Of *gomer* they say:

> Hebrew ʿ , normally untransliterated, is occasionally rendered by g in the Septuagint, and hence in the Vulgate (it has been retained in English in a few words such as *Gomorrah*). 16th-cent. versions usually adopted forms with ʿ untransliterated, and hence the present word was replaced by omer n.

Comment: I didn't sat omer has Gomorrah as etymon.